# glob(): sort only by name (not by extentions too)

Tags: glob

glob() sort my files as follows:

```
ABC_file.pdf
DEF_file.pdf
GHJ_file.pdf
ABC_file.zip
```

But I want sort them *only* by name (not by name and extension too):

```
ABC_file.pdf
ABC_file.zip
DEF_file.pdf
GHJ_file.pdf
```

How to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your `glob()` call (with the mask)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
glob($fileMask, GLOB_NOSORT);
```

According the PHP manual:

> **`GLOB_NOSORT`** - Return files as they appear in the directory (no sorting)

Comment: I tried but the sorting order seems random (perhaps the same as when you make a 'ls' on remote filesystem). Anyway, with this option, the listing  appears a bit faster